# Swift multithreading console app

Tags: swift

I have a console app on Swift3 that read line by line from very large file.txt (~200GB):

```
guard let reader = LineReader(path: "/Path/to/file.txt") else { return; }

for line in reader {
    // do something with each line      
}
```

It takes about 8+ hours to read all data from file. My server has 6 hardware cores, how to read this file in 6 threads?

LineReader from here: https://github.com/andrewwoz/LineReader

PS. Files from the beginning is separate by 1GB per file.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: step 1: don't make 200gb txt files

Comment: Multithreading this would require you having a safe way of splitting the file into multiple chunks to be processed separately. Given the layout of your file, is that possible?

Comment: Fire up XCode Instruments and measure where all the time is spent. Then optimize. What operating system is this anyway?

Comment: File is access.log on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The first thing to determine is if the problem is CPU or IO bound. If you are reading from a busy conventional disk drive and your problem is IO bound, more threads are going to make it worse.

Comment: Problem is in CPU, one core is 100% during all time app works. SSD is about 10-20% use.

Comment: I've tested it in Xcode with a 2GB file. It takes 27s and is indeed CPU bound. (It would take about 45 min with a 200 GB file.) About 75% of the time is spent in `String.init(cString:)`. This initializer carefully verifies it's valid UTF-8 input and otherwise replace the problematic characters with a special Unicode placeholder. It seems this comes at a price.

Comment: @Codo With each line I need to do some tasks: make array from the line, take item array[N], try to find character in the item, ... This task take a lot of CPU time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!!! This solution works only if you read file using **POSIX fopen()** like here: https://github.com/andrewwoz/LineReader

```
let reader = LineReader(path: pathToFile)
var threads = [Thread]()

func readTxtFile() {
   while  let line = reader?.nextLine {
     autoreleasepool {
       // To do with each line
   }}
}

for threadNumber in 0...threadsCount-1 {
   threads.append(Thread(){ readTxtFile() })
   threads[threadNumber].start()
}

select(0, nil, nil, nil, nil)
```

Also the real time profit only with hardware cores, not with HT threads. If your CPU has 2 cores and 4 threads, use 2 threads in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Never thought about multithread reading a .txt file with 200gb but I'd probably let the console detect how many cores (e.x. 6core)are available and split it into (e.x. 6parts). (-> One part for every process)
As far as I know Ubuntu will automatically evenly distribute to processes.
Hope this helped

Comment: Than you. Could you please help, not understand how you propose to execute 6 processes?